# Can't find KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG in StreamsConfig

Tags: apache-kafka

I followed sample codes from http://kafka.apache.org/0100/javadoc/index.html?org/apache/kafka/streams/KafkaStreams.html

For lines

```java
props.put(StreamsConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);
props.put(StreamsConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);
props.put(StreamsConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
props.put(StreamsConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
```

The four constants from `StreamsConfig` can't be found. Instead, I found them in `ProducerConfig` and `ConsumerConfig` respectively.

```java
props.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);
props.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);
props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
```

My kafka-stream version is 0.10.0.0

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
  <artifactId>kafka-streams</artifactId>
  <version>0.10.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Do I make something wrong? Or the constants from `ProducerConfig` and `ConsumerConfig` are actually what the document means?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Serializers and deserializers got merged to a single *SerDe* abstraction and thus, the config parameters got merge to `StreamsConfig.KEY_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG` and `StreamsConfig.VALUE_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG` (the example shows the old **0.9.x tech-preview** once). Do **not** use producer or consumer configuration parameters!

The correct way to set SerDe is as follows (also consider the new class names):

```java
props.put(StreamsConfig.KEY_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, Serdes.String().getClass().getName());
props.put(StreamsConfig.VALUE_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, Serdes.String().getClass().getName());
```

It's a bug in the documentation: https://github.com/apache/kafka/pull/1450

Also have a look here: http://docs.confluent.io/3.0.0/streams/developer-guide.html#data-types-and-serialization

Comment: Thank you @Matthias very much. I guess the StringSerde.class is Serdes.StringSerde.class, isn't it?

Comment: Yes. I just corrected my answer. You should specify the name of the class as String.